# React Native Android: how to remove "overscroll effect" of ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, react-native

Added ScrollView Component in React Native Android, and when you scroll down or up all the way, it show an overscroll effect. How do you remove this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As of React Native 0.42, an `overScrollMode` prop is available to set the overscroll mode for each ScrollView:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#overscrollmode

Comment: The link the the answer is dead, here's the new location: https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#overscrollmode-android

Answer (score 12):

Until this option is added, I have to do it for the whole app using styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:overScrollMode">never</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Where do you add this?

Comment: res/values/styles.xml