# React Native Flat list shadow effect

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to disable a shadow effect when my flat list hits its limit on Android, but I didn't succeed so far.

I've looked the documentation but I couldn't find any solution. I also tried some scroll view props in a effort to make it happen, but got no results either.

Any help would be appreciated, either to disable this (if possible) or change the color.

Here is an image as an example that shows the  effect I'm talking about:

[image]

Comment: Probably a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34403748/react-native-android-how-to-remove-overscroll-effect-of-scrollview. The relevant docs are here https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#overscrollmode-android

Comment: I'm gonna try that, but I'm not sure if it works for flat list.

Comment: It should, FlatLists are just fancy ScrollViews.

Comment: No problem, glad it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

There is a property on the scrollview that also works on the flatlist, which is overScrollMode.

Just set it like never before and it stops appearing at the end of the list scroll